Ubuntu Studio HDMI audio working only in stereo
Trying Ubuntu Studio for the first time, hoping to eventually use it as the base for both my media center and a replacement for my Windows DAW tools.
For testing, I've installed the current version (24.04) on a not-ancient PC (Dell D09S, which I think has an i3 with Intel graphics).
From there the HDMI is going to a Samsung Frame TV, whose optical audio out is going to an Onkyo TX-DS747 tuner, which decodes, amplifies, and routes it to my surround speakers. This is working for other HDMI sources.
If I enable HDMI audio output from Ubuntu Studio, stereo tests work, though left-right are reversed from what it says we should expect. It's possible I just didn't notice an L/R reversal when setting up the system, though I'd have hoped to catch that on other media.
If I try the HDMI 5.1 surround mode from Ubuntu Studio, I get garbled output, usually from speakers other than the one I asked for a test on. Best guess is that the encoding being produced either isn't correct, or at least isn't what the Samsung TV is expecting.
Admittedly Samsung's HDMI implementation has some quirks, and the tuner is old enough that it's possible it doesn't support the modern protocols. But as I said, other HDMI surround audio through this path (DVD player HDMI to TV, TV optical to tuner) seems to be fine.
QUESTION:

Is this another version of 5.1 audio via HDMI only plays on two channels? If so I would expect all surround from the TV to be lost, and that's not what I'm hearing when running a movie.

I've seen mention of HDMI audio problems in 24.04. Would these symptoms be part of that issue? If so, I can wait for a fix.

Is there anything else I can do, preferably with equipment I have on hand, to better determine what's failing where and hopefully at least contribute to finding a solution?



No idea if it's relevant, but the beep command tells me "Error: could not open any device." So whatever is going on, primitive Linux speaker support isn't connecting to the HDMI audio, which perplexes me somewhat.

Can I say I'm a bit disappointed at the silence? Given that Ubuntu is actively pushing Studio as a replacement for Windows and Mac based multimedia production, I hoped at least to get a pointer to debugging tips for Studio"s sound handling. Or to get downvoted and told where to go instead. Silence suggests that Studio has no users, which would be disappointing; I really want to get my DAW off Windows onto something  which will continue to support my older professors.

According to the head of Ubuntu Studio, it is indeed a duplicate of  the linked question.

Ok.  Closed as dupe.

I should add he said it’s not specific to Ubuntu Studio but it related to how PipeWire works with HDMI devices.

Ok, though it sounded as if the problem might actually be in the conversion from HDMI to  SPDIF not correctly transcoding all the channels. In which case, feeding the HDMI to an HDMI switcher/amp and taking the audio there before it gets to the TV -- or using the audio return channel on the HDMI connection to the TV -- might dodge the problem by taking the SPDIF return out of the equation...? (See XKCD re standards.)

Apparently this is indeed a dupe. But I can't close it as such while the bounty is open, so I'm going to check this off and drop it into the bit bucket.
